# Merge results of 2 inner queries into single result in SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms

I am trying to merge results of two inner join SQL queries into a single result. This works if both queries return rows; otherwise it returns no rows.

If either of the subqueries doesn't have a record it should be null but the other subquery must show its result. But this query returns empty for both when it has a result for one subquery.

```
select CASE sovereign.MaxDate
    WHEN null THEN ''
    ELSE sovereign.MaxDate END AS SovereignDate,
    CASE economic.MaxDate
    WHEN null THEN ''
    ELSE economic.MaxDate END AS EconomicDate
from
    (select top 1 Doc_Pub_Date as MaxDate
    from content_ext.dbo.[sovereignrisk] rc
    where rc.Code = 'BJ'
    order by Doc_Pub_Date desc
    ) as sovereign
,
    (select top 1 Doc_Pub_Date as MaxDate
    from content_ext.dbo.[credit_conditions] rc
    where rc.Code = 'BJ'
    order by Doc_Pub_Date desc
    ) as economic
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Merge how? Show us sample result for each query, and also the merged result you expect.

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using. Some product specific constructions used.

Comment: You should use an (explicit) FULL OUTER JOIN, rather than just using the comma (implicit inner join) to separate the 2 aliased sub-queries.  Then you will get results if either of the sub-queries returns a result.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins for some back info).  Note that you will still not get a result if BOTH of the sub-queries return no result

Comment: The purpose of the JOIN will not be to relate the two sub-queries, but rather to ensure that you get a resultset that can be used if only one of the sub-queries returns a result

Comment: You also obviously do not understand that by doing SELECT * from table1, SELECT * from table2 - that comma is implicitly applying a JOIN between the two

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "merge" is vague. You don't say how output is a function of inputs. You are not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Don't try to cram everything into too few words, phrases & sentences. Please clarify via edits, not comments. From your comment about both tables, you maybe want a FULL JOIN. That's a faq. Not all SQLs support FULL JOIN. What is yours? How to simulate it is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example of how changing the way the sub-queries are used in the entire query will return a result, even if one of the sub-queries does not return a result.

```
CREATE TABLE #a (val int);
CREATE TABLE #b (val2 int);

INSERT INTO #a VALUES (1);

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 val FROM #a
) AS [aa],
(
    SELECT TOP 1 val2 FROM #b
) AS [bb];

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 val FROM #a
) AS [aa] FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 val2 FROM #b
) AS [bb] ON 1=1;

DROP TABLE #a;
DROP TABLE #b;
```

You can see from the two different resultsets that the query using a FULL OUTER JOIN will always return a result if at least ONE of the sub-queries has a result.